# Deserialize jackson in spring boot

Tags: java, json, jackson, spring-boot

I am getting two types of json by calling RestTemplate

```
{"results":[{"testing":{"name":"soham"}},{"testing":{"firstname":"john","lastname":"don"}}]}
```

Now I am parsing data using JsonDeserializer

```
public class CustomJacksonDeserialize extends JsonDeserializer<Activity> {
    @Override
    public Activity deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws
            IOException, NullPointerException {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        JsonNode actualObj = objectMapper.readTree(jsonParser.getValueAsString());

            return new Activity(actualObj.get("name").asText());
    }
}
```

Here is my class

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = CustomJacksonDeserialize.class)
public class Activity {

    private String name;

    public Activity(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Now my question is how to parse this json.`@JsonDeserialize` isn't helpful in this case.Any other options?Or how to use `@JsonDeserialize` in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify `CustomJacksonDeserialize` like this :

```
class CustomJacksonDeserialize extends JsonDeserializer<Activity> {
    @Override
    public Activity deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException,
            NullPointerException {

        JsonNode jsonNode = jsonParser.readValueAsTree();

        String name=jsonNode.get("results").get(0).get("testing").get("name").asText();

        return new Activity(name);
    }
}
```

**Second Approach:**
Alternatively If you can also de-serilaize this JSON using Object mapper itself This does not require CustomJacksonDeserialize :

```
String jsonString = "{\"results\":[{\"testing\":{\"name\":\"soham\"}},{\"testing\":{\"firstname\":\"john\",\"lastname\":\"don\"}}]}";
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

JsonNode jsonNode = objectMapper.readTree(jsonString);
JsonNode resultNode=jsonNode.get("results");
String name = resultNode.get(0).get("testing").get("name").asText();

Activity activity=new Activity(name);

String firstName=  resultNode.get(1).get("testing").get("firstname").asText();
String lastName=  resultNode.get(1).get("testing").get("lastname").asText();

Activity2 activity2=new Activity2(firstName, lastName);
```

**NOTE** : I have extracted value of `name`, `firstname` and `lastname` for given JSON, you can modify this logic accordingly.

**Third Approach:** Here I can iterate through the JSON array and will create separate objects of both the activities:

```
String jsonString = "{\"results\":[{\"testing\":{\"name\":\"soham\"}},{\"testing\":{\"firstname\":\"john\",\"lastname\":\"don\"}}]}";

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        JsonNode jsonNode = objectMapper.readTree(jsonString);

        JsonNode resultNode = jsonNode.get("results");

        List<Activity> activityList1 = new ArrayList<Activity>();

        List<Activity2> activityList2 = new ArrayList<Activity2>();

        for (int i = 0; i < resultNode.size(); i++) {

            JsonNode testingNode = resultNode.get(i).get("testing");

            if (testingNode.has("name")) {
                String name = testingNode.get("name").asText();

                Activity activity = new Activity(name);
                activityList1.add(activity);

            }

            if (testingNode.has("firstname")) {
                String firstName = testingNode.get("firstname").asText();
                String lastName = testingNode.get("lastname").asText();

                Activity2 activity2 = new Activity2(firstName, lastName);
                activityList2.add(activity2);

            }

        }
```

Comment: I want to get the firstname and lastname also in different Pojo classes?

Comment: you can create one more de-serializer for another class and in that de-serializer you can return instance of another POJO class,

Comment: @Soham I have updated my answer, I think second approach more suits your requirement.

Comment: You are not getting my point,I can't return both Activity and Activity2 from the CustomJacksonDeserialize. So what is the solution?Do I have to use two CustomJacksonDeserialize class,if I have to then how?

Comment: Hey, Please see my answer again, I have added one more approach that doesn't require any CustomJacksonDeserializer

Comment: Thanks,but I can't do  like this resultNode.get(1),because I don't know the size of the result and it may be fullname  instead of name or firstname.It's fully dynamic.Can you suggest like if I distinguish by declaring some enum,if it's possible.

Comment: See my updated answer I think third approach will solve your query :).

Comment: Thanks for your answer.It will solved but I am looking for better answer like avoiding if else,if it can automatically mapped to any pojo classes.But thanks a lot for your answer.